# Couldn't find Timetable with 'id'=clas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Generated a timetable scaffold. Then later created a new action "clas" in my timetables_controller.rb.

**timetables_controller.rb**

```
class TimetablesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_timetable, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :clas]
def clas
  @classtimetable = Timetable.where(params[:clas])
end

//other actions

def set_timetable
  @timetable = Timetable.find(params[:id])
end

def timetable_params
  params.require(:timetable).permit(:day, :clas, :one_teacher, :one_sub, :two_teacher, :two_sub, :three_teacher, :three_sub, :four_teacher, :four_sub, :five_teacher, :five_sub, :six_teacher, :six_sub, :seven_teacher, :seven_sub, :eight_teacher, :eight_sub)
end
end
```

Created form_for to the action "clas". Need to pass the select option values as params to the controller

**clas.html.erb**

```
<% form_for @classtimetable, :url => clas_timetables_path, :html => { :method => :post} do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label "Select class" %>
  <% values = ["1c", "2c", "3c", "4d", "5i"] %>
  <%= f.select :clas, options_for_select(values) %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Submit"%>
</div>
<% end %>

<% @classtimetable.each do |class_timetable| %>
<%= class_timetable.day %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :timetables do
member do
  get 'clas'
end
end
```

I need to get all the day for the class in my clas.html.erb page. Which is done by selecting the class from dropdown and submit. The value should be passed in params when i click submit.
don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate on when are you getting the error?

Comment: when i switch to url "http://localhost:3000/timetables/clas"

Answer (score 2):

Add controller in `form_for` tag,

```
<% form_for @classtimetable, :url => { :controller => "your-controller-name", :action => :clas } do |f| %>
```

Or you can directly write like this,

```
<% form_for @classtimetable, :url => clas_timetables_path, :html => { :method => :post} do |f| %>
```

Change `before_action` like,

```
before_action :set_timetable, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :clas]
```

You would change `collection` to `member` and pass `id`

```
resources :timetables do
member do
  get 'clas'
end
end
```

Comment: still getting the same error 
undefined method `model_name' for Timetable::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class

Comment: now getting error Couldn't find Timetable without an ID

Comment: Couldn't find Timetable with 'id'=clas .
what do you mean by pass id ?

Comment: Are you getting `id` using `params[:id]` on view page?

Comment: you can check my above question with update as you said

Comment: You would want to pass the id of the time table for the clas, since it is on member, it requires the id

Comment: The url for form_for method would be clas_timetables_path(@classtimetable)

Comment: getting same error "Couldn't find Timetable with 'id'=clas"

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `form_tag` like this,

```
<% form_for @classtimetable, :url => clas_timetables_path(@classtimetable), :method => :post do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
def clas
  @classtimetable = Timetable.where(timetable_params[:clas]).first
end
```

Comment: @rinold according to your routes, you need to pass your timetable id since your route is on member

Comment: the url should be `localhost:3000/timetables/:timetable_id/clas/`

Comment: when i change my route form "member" to "collection"
i'm getting error "Couldn't find Timetable without an ID"

Comment: remove :class action from before_action

Comment: getting error "undefined method `model_name' for Timetable::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class" in my form_for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79630/discussion-between-rinold-and-amit-badheka-pykih-staff).

Answer (score 0):

First I recognized: You used get in routes, and post in form. So the actions won't match.
Second: You've written:

> still getting the same error undefined method `model_name' for Timetable::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class

So look, how you defined @classtimetable

```
  @classtimetable = Timetable.where(params[:clas])
```

This is a relation, not the ActiveRecord, you want to find by clas. The error will be thrown on this line:

```
<% form_for @classtimetable, :url => clas_timetables_path, :html => { :method => :post} do |f| %>
```

form_for expects as first argument an ActiveRecord or something similar (at least something extending ActiveModel::Naming). Since I do not see your definition of Timetable, I just guess, it has an attribute called clas and you want to find the Timetable with clas equals the selection in that form. So it would be:

```
@classtimetable = Timetable.find_by(clas: params[:clas])
```

what is the same as:

```
@classtimetable = Timetable.where(clas: params[:clas]).first
```

To get the first element from that Relation, you tried to use.

Third: Since you did define your route to be a member route, it should expect an id in clas_timetable_path. Since you load @timetable in clas action in before_filter, I think you want to have there:

```
<% form_for @classtimetable, :url => clas_timetables_path(@timetable), :html => { :method => :get} do |f| %>
```